# Find Provenance Data For Flowfile Within a Processor

Tags: apache-nifi, flowfile

I am attempting to develop a NiFi processor that would extend the functionality of the built-in processor "Monitor Activity".

The problem I am attempting to solve is that in my application, I would have multiple flows entering the processor, with the processor alerting by email when no flowfiles arrive within a certain time period. However, if only one of the flows stop, no alert will be triggered.

I would like to modify the processor such that it would be able to distinguish between  the different flows and alert accordingly.

In order to do this, I would need a way to deferentiate between flowfiles originating from one processor and another.
I am aware NiFi keeps detailed provenance records that can be easily accessed from within the GUI interface but I'm unable to find an easy way of accessing this information programmatically from within processor code.

Comment: It sounds like you could build this as a flow using existing processors, and reuse it as a versioned process group?

Comment: @Sdairs This sounds like an elegant solution, but I've been instructed to build a processor to these specifications. These design choices are not in my hands.

Comment: I don't know that you can do what you want to do, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492762/nifi-how-to-get-the-current-processor-name-and-processor-group-name-through-the without having say, an UpdateAttribute between the source processor and your custom processor, then reading attribute.